# subtract label values in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I want to subtract number from Label on button click.When i do that on button click values is subtracted just once, and on second click on the same button nothing is happen.I cannot figure out what is the problem?-Here is my code:

```
  protected void btnTest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        Session["Counter"] = newValue;

        if (ViewState["Markici"] != null)
        {
            dtCurrentTable = (DataTable)ViewState["Markici"];
            ViewState["Markici"] = dtCurrentTable;
            dtCurrentTable = (DataTable)ViewState["Markici"];

            GridView2.DataSource = dtCurrentTable;
            GridView2.DataBind();
            var clickedRow = ((Button)sender).NamingContainer as GridViewRow;
            var clickedIndex = clickedRow.RowIndex;

            decimal old = dtCurrentTable.Rows[clickedIndex].Field<decimal>("Kolicina");

            decimal oldIznos = dtCurrentTable.Rows[clickedIndex].Field<decimal>("VkIznos");
            decimal VkDanok = dtCurrentTable.Rows[clickedIndex].Field<decimal>("VkDanok");
            string Cena1 = dtCurrentTable.Rows[clickedIndex].Field<string>("Cena1");
            int TarifaID = dtCurrentTable.Rows[clickedIndex].Field<Int32>("TarifaID");



            decimal newIznos = oldIznos - Convert.ToDecimal(Cena1);

            dtCurrentTable.Rows[clickedIndex].SetField("Kolicina", newValue.ToString());
            dtCurrentTable.Rows[clickedIndex].SetField("VkIznos", newIznos.ToString());

 //Here i do the operation 
            decimal minus = Convert.ToDecimal(Label42.Text) - Convert.ToDecimal(Cena1);
            Label26.Text = minus.ToString();
           }
```

Comment: What do you man by nothing happens ?

Comment: Post solution as answer and accept it so question can be closed.

Answer (score 0):

All the time I was subtracting in wrong label..

```
decimal minus = Convert.ToDecimal(Label42.Text) - Convert.ToDecimal(Cena1);
Label42.Text = minus.ToString();
```